# Send refresh to page

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way to send a redirect to a page which have already been rendered, I need this because I'm doing some server-side scripting and have provided a loading page for the user.

I'm probably thinking about something like socket.io or faye, but I'd like to know if there is a better way. Also I do no have any plans of redirected more than one user at a time, so I don't know if the services above would be a bit over kill or anything?
It have to be a specific user, as I'm dealing with some facebook, so it would be rather embarrassing if I redirected a wrong user to a wrong facebook.

Ps. I'm only looking for ways to do this in node js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't want to use a socket library you could set up your own long-polling solution.

A pretty good explanation of this can be found here http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/12/02/diving-into-node-js-a-long-polling-example/

It doesn't exactly match your use case but you can get an idea of what it's doing.

With that said, I'm a proponent of not reinventing the wheel and socket.io and faye will certainly help you do what you want.

Comment: Well, I ended up using socket.io.